# converting string to hex

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I have a string that has 0111111100000000000000000000101

I wanted to convert this to hex, so I used the code below

```
    int assembledHex;
    sscanf(buffer, "%x", &assembledHex);
    printf("this is the assembled hex %x\n",assembledHex);
```

but when I print it, it gives me 101. I thought sscanf can convert to hex from a string, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it. The result I want is 0x3F800005

Comment: Is this supposed to be a binary representation? Or you want the character codes to be encoded in hex?

Comment: yes they are binary numbers stored in a character array

Comment: Roll up every four digits from the back into a number in the range `[0, 16)` and use that as an index into an array `"0123456789ABCDEF"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not checked or anything, and also quite slow, but it's a quick start:

```
unsigned int bin_to_int(const char *s) {
    int i;
    unsigned int result;

    result = 0;

    if (s[0] == '1') result++;

    for (i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        result <<= 1;

        if (s[i] == '1') {
            result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You also need to move the `result <<= 1;` to before the if clause, or there will be one to many shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sscanf` is reading the string as HEX, but the string is written in binary. You get "101" because `int` can only store the first 8 digits - each digit is 4 bits, so two digits=8 bits=1 byte, and 8 digits are 4 bytes, which is the size of `int`. So you actually store "00000101", buy `printf` does not print the leading zeroes so you get "101".

Comment: ok so how can I solve the problem without writing my own converter function

Comment: C does not have a bin2hex converter function in the standard library, so you need to either write your own converter, or download someone else's converter.  
  
I wouldn't worry about this too much. This is good for an exercise, but you probably won't have to convert binary to HEX in your programming career. While the computer stores and uses data in binary format, programs, even if they are written in assembly, can only access that data in 8 bit chunks(and this is why any binary converter function will be relatively slow). Data is never stored as binary in strings.